# jasper report does not show up when executing the jar file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

it works fine in when I run it in Netbeans but it's won't show in executable jar file here's my codes

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    rep.siapkan_report_dengan_parameter("report4.jrxml", "Report", "periode",tCari.getText());
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}


public void siapkan_report_dengan_parameter(      
    String nama_report,
    String direktori,
    String namaparameter,
    String isiparameter){      

    konek.openConnection();       

    Properties systemProp = System.getProperties();

    // Ambil current dir
    String currentDir = systemProp.getProperty("user.dir");

    File dir = new File(currentDir);
    String reportName = nama_report;
    String reportDirName = direktori;

    File fileRpt;
    String fullPath = "";
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] isiDir = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < isiDir.length; i++) {
            fileRpt = new File(currentDir + File.separatorChar + isiDir[i] + File.separatorChar +
                    reportDirName + File.separatorChar + reportName);
            if (fileRpt.isFile()) { // Cek apakah file  ada 
                fullPath = fileRpt.toString();                  
            } 
        } 
    }         

    String[] subRptDir = fullPath.split(reportName);

    try {

        // Persiapkan parameter untuk Report
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put(namaparameter, isiparameter);
        try {
            JasperReport JRpt = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fullPath);                
            JasperPrint JPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JRpt, parameters,konek.conn);
            if(JPrint.getPages().isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Data Untuk Kriteria :\n" + isiparameter +"\nTidak Ada", 
                "Peringatan", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }else{
                JasperViewer.viewReport(JPrint, false);                
            }
        } catch (Exception rptexcpt) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "a", 
                "Peringatan", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "b", 
                "Peringatan", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

thanks in advance!

my libraries are:

- common-beanutils-1.7
- commons-collections-2.1
- commons-digester-1.7
- commons-javaflow-20060411
- commons-logging-1.1
- jasperreports-3.0.1
- jdt-compiler-3.1.1
- jfreechart-1.0.3
- poi-3.0.1-FINAL-20070705

Comment: What errors do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not loading jasper report as a stream. So, try adding this:

```
InputStream st = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fullPath);

try {
            JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(st);
            JasperReport JRpt = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);                
            JasperPrint JPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JRpt, parameters,konek.conn);
            if(JPrint.getPages().isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "Data Untuk Kriteria :\n" + isiparameter +"\nTidak Ada", 
                "Peringatan", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }else{
                JasperViewer.viewReport(JPrint, false);                
            }
        } catch (Exception rptexcpt) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                "a", 
                "Peringatan", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Also, add your `.jrxml` files in some package in your project before you export it to `.jar`.

Path (fullPath) you will pass will be something like: `/com/report/nameofreport.jrxml`.

Comment: thanks, I've added your suggestion but it still shows some errors

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with your code... Just add following libraries. Don't use latest jasper libraries. that is the reason to not load your reports through jar executable. (use ireport 5.5.0 libraries). Code i use is below

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure(new NullAppender());
    //InputStream st = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/SalesInvoiceCustomerCopy.jrxml");
    try
    {
        Connection connect = conn.open();

        String report2 = "H:\\Higher Diploma Project\\FinalHD\\src\\Reports\\SalesInvoiceCustomerCopy.jrxml";
        JasperReport rep2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report2);
        JasperPrint rep_print2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rep2,null,connect);
        JasperPrintManager.printReport(rep_print2,false);

        String report = "H:\\Higher Diploma Project\\FinalHD\\src\\Reports\\SalesInvoice.jrxml";
        JasperReport rep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint rep_print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rep,null,connect);
        JasperPrintManager.printReport(rep_print,false);

        try
        {
            pst =conn.open().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO invoice_balanace VALUES (?,?,?,?)") ;
            pst.setString(1, txtInvoiceNo.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txtValue.getText());
            pst.setString(3, totDisc.getText());
            pst.setString(4, txtNetVal.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);}

        idUpdater();
    }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ e);}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite efficient to use a compiled jasper report into your jar file. I'll suggest you reference the report from a location on your pc e.g., C: drive.

It'll also be Best if you have a permanent folder that can be easily accessed. It could be `C:/<project name>/report/<your-report>`.

This approach enables you to distribute it with ease.